# Wordpress Page html code so Google Custom Search box is OVER an image

Tags: html, wordpress

I want to create a wordpress page which I can put the html code to do the following please

1) Google custom search box (which i can get the GCS code from google) but it has to be OVER an image. not above or below the image :). image will be hosted on my site media library

2) round icons buttons below the search box similar to the one i have attached which bounces when mouse over (images of these icons can be changed and destination urls assigned by me)

the attached example is the yahoo new tab extension for firefox

any help is appreciated. 
i have attached the sample page image and the view source code of that page to help understand my context. the difference is that the search will be by google instead of yahoo

[image]

thank you friends!

view code below as its not letting me attached doc

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="newtab.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="brand.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="bg" class="flexContainer bgImage">
<div id="bookmarksAbsolute">
    <div id="bookmarksFlex" class="uiBG"></div>
</div>

<div id="searchTrendingNowContainer"></div>

<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="uiBlur"></div>
    <div id="uiContainer">
        <form id="submitSearchNew">
            <img id="magnifierNew" src="icons/mag3.svg">
            <input type="text" id="searchBoxNew" autocomplete="off" name="p" tabindex="1">
        </form>
        <div id="searchSuggestContainerNew" class="searchSuggestContainerNew displayNone"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="urlHidden"><span id="urlContent"></span></div>
</div>

<div id="darkOverlay"></div>
<div id="pageFooter">
    <div id="ownerContainer">
        <a id="ownerName" class="credit"></a>
        <a id="onFlickr" class="credit flickr"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="newTopSitesContainer" id="topSites"></div>

    <div id="urlInfo"></div>
</div>

<div class="dropup" id="dropupMenu">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button"  data-toggle="dropdown">
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu options-list">
            <li><a id="toggleViewText" class="toggleText unselectable"> </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li id="tnDiv" class="displayNone"><a id="toggleTN" class="unselectable"> </a></li>
            <li id="tnDivider" class="divider displayNone"></li>
            <li><a id="editButton" class="unselectable"> </a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a id="feedBack" class="feedBackLink unselectable"> </a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
<script src='newtab.js'></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand you, if you need show up input tag and image in other image?

If is it yes, use z-index CSS for image for example:

```
<div class="base"> <!-- z-index = 1 -->
<input type="search" class="search" /> <!-- z-index = 2 -->

<div class="buttons_footer"> <!-- z-index = 2 -->
<button></button>
<button></button>
<button></button>
.....
</div>
</div>
```

I hope to help

Comment: hi Daniel thanks for the note. 1) if you look at my attached image, ( [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MCgmT.jpg) bascially i can create the google custom search box into my wordpress page by popping in the code G gives me. however if i want to OVERLAY this search box over an image i want is the tricky part i am trying to figure out. 2) also the round buttons below that which bounces to mouse (this is optional haha). any ideas on the first requirement please?

Comment: so bascially i want to create a different page for each background image with a google custom search box within the image as in the example. (Google custom search engine gives me the code to pop in the html but the question is how do i overlay over an image)

Comment: Add CSS z-index in element, if adding z-index 1 for image and adding z-index 2 in input element and buttons, the input and buttons element show up over the image.